# pandas - merge rows and subtotal counts based on regular time intervals

Tags: python, pandas

I am counting the frequency based every 30 min. after I did this work for one dataframe, it merges with another one (see yellow part in below table which disorders the format). Is there an elegant way to re-organize the data to maintain the consistency format (i.e. merge the same period frequency togeter by every 30 min)

[image]

The expected results (sum up the yellow part count by every 30 min):

[image]

Comment: My initial guess is that you have to use `.normalize()` before merge. If you can post the sample of your two data frames and the expected results it will be helpful.

Comment: the yellow part is a dataframe, the rest part is another one which is complete and consistent. what I want is to embed the yellow part into the rest part (see added expected result)